# Dependency Injection and Entities

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap3

I have two classes and have one to many  relationship as shown below

```
public class User
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public IList<Address> Addresses{get;set}
}

public class Address
{
   public string StreetAddress{get;set;}
   public User User{get;set;}
}
```

To add address to user I need to initiate Addresses property in User constructor as

```
public User()
{
   this.Addresses=new List<Address>();

}
```

Is this scenario good candidate to use DI to initiate List or should I initiate the Address list in constructor as shown.

Comment: I doubt it, are you just initialising it to an empty list? If so, what is there to inject here? I'm not sure you quite understand what dependency injection is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the the address data itself is required to construct an instance of User, it may be a candidate for DI.  But if's just a matter of making sure the list is instantiated, then your code is correct as-is.

Answer (score 0):

In this case Dependency Injection would be overkill. Dependency Injection is usually used to initialize complex networks of services. Here you are dealing with a network of data objects that map to the piece of world you are translating into code: a composition between User and Address is therefore sufficient, and you must initialize collections in the constructor.